# How to get element:hover background with javascript and CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess

I want to get :hover css for multiple elements with js/jquery and I already have the working function but I get this eror:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
ruleList = sheetList[i].cssRules;
```

Function:

```
function getStyleBySelector(selector){
    var sheetList = document.styleSheets;
    var ruleList;
    var i, j;
    for (i=sheetList.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        ruleList = sheetList[i].cssRules;
        for (j=0; j<ruleList.length; j++){
            if (ruleList[j].type == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE && ruleList[j].selectorText == selector){
                return ruleList[j].style;
            }   
        }
    }
    return null;
}
getStyleBySelector('#desc a:hover').background
```

I know it's a CORS problem, because I import CSS from another domain + google fonts but I have this in my **.htaccess**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This is more a firefox bug. Any help with this please?

Comment: This is not a bug. You can not read things from other domains. Your .htaccess is only yours, not others'.

Comment: I know it's not a bug, but I'm looking for a solution beacuse the .htaccess is not on my server. It located on the 2nd server, from where I get all the files.

Comment: Why not using `document.querySelector('#desc a:hover')[i].background` in a for loop? This would easily solve your use case unless you have a special reason to use the rules itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of solving this issue:

1) Don’t use the original CSS rules for it but query the DOM instead:

```
var $selector = document.querySelector('#desc a:hover');
var computedStyle;
var background = [];

// Read value of background and write into background array
for (var i = 0; i < $selector.length; i++) {
    computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle($selector[i], null);
    background.push(computedStyle.getPropertyValue('background'));
}
```

2) Exclude external styelsheets:
*This excludes foreign stylesheets so you don’t run into security issues (but it then misses out matching selectors of external stylesheets)*

```
var getCSSHost = function (href) {
    var fakeLinkOfSheet = document.createElement('a');

    fakeLinkOfSheet.href = href;
    return fakeLinkOfSheet.host;    
};

var sheetHost = getCSSHost(stylesheet.href);

if ((sheetHost !== window.location.host)) {
    return; //exit early, i.e. return false
}
// else go on
```

3) Proxy external resources
*As John suggested in his answer you could also proxy the external resources to the same server and port to get it working. This is a big effort and you should probably consider this if nothing else works only.*

Comment: Thanks. Btw, 1st example retuns `$selector is null`

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot modify the header sent by Google/other domains. We have to go for a workaround.

I think a way to do this is that you set up a proxy to those resources: i.e., you request your server for those files, your server grab those files, sent them to you with appropriate header(i.e. set those CORS headers). And then you can do this.